# Hosting a standalone ruby script

Tags: ruby, heroku

I have a simple ruby program to check for emails and notify the user via SMS. Now I want to host this script on a dedicated server. Can I host it on Heroku. If so how?

Answer (score 2):

Write an executable script, say `mail_checker.rb`.  Create a project with a `Procfile` specifying this process should be run:

```
mail_checker: ruby ./mail_checker.rb
```

Comment: I updated my Procfile like this and deployed with command 'git push heroku master'. But when I checked the logs its generating an error saying 'Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch'

Answer (score 0):

Put this in your Procfile:

```
worker: ruby ./mail_checker.rb
```

You need to remember that this will run your app as a Worker Dyno and it will be always be online. It depends on your script's code how it will work.